# BIML -> Use existing package and add a data flow

Tags: ssis, biml

Is it possible to use existing `SSIS` package and add just containers (with data flow tasks) using `BIML` script

Comment: No, it will overwrite your existing ssis packages

Comment: But you can use BimlExpress to import your package, and then add containers and generate it, and it will ask if you want to overwrite (or you can name the package something else?)

Answer (score 0):

As commenters have already stated this is not possible.  Biml is destructive by design.

If you want to add new elements to an existing package you will need to import the package and generate the Biml required to output it, which can now be done via Mist/BimlStudio, BimlOnline and as of the latest release BimlExpress.

Once you have the Biml for your existing package, you can add the new containers that you require and then recreate your entire package, overwriting the old one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use BimlExpress to import your package, and then add containers and generate it, and it will ask if you want to overwrite (or you can name the package something else?)